# Python Gtk.CellRendererText() color

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, renderer, listcellrenderer, cellrenderer

This treeview has 5 columns with a list of usb devices details , it's showing Device name , Model , Serial number and status , it's all showing fine on the list , what I am trying to achieve is colour code the "status"
column only ,if the "status" is READ-WRITE then colour coded as RED otherwise GREEN. The code below is currently colour code entire column as RED ,it's just ignoring any READ-ONLY devices. I've spent a couple of hours finding the answer online but can't find any . Can anyone help me with this ?

```
def build_device_list(self):
    self.dev_store_len = len(self.device_list_store)
    for i, column_title in enumerate(["Device", "Model", "Serial Number","Size"]):
        self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, self.renderer, text=i)
        self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column)
        column.set_sort_column_id(i)
    self.renderer_status = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column_status = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Status",self.renderer_status, text=4)
    for x in range(0, self.dev_store_len):
        if self.device_list_store[x][4] == "READ-WRITE":
           self.renderer_status.set_property("foreground", "Red")
           self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column_status)
        else:
           self.renderer_status.set_property("foreground", "Green")
           self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column_status)

    self.scrollable_treelist = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.scrollable_treelist.set_vexpand(True)
    self.outter_box.pack_start(self.scrollable_treelist,False,True,0)
    self.scrollable_treelist.add(self.device_list_treeview)
```

Comment: What are the 2 asterisks by `self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column_status)**`?

Comment: I am not too sure , I didn't note there're two asterisks . I've removed them from it .

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: No , it doesn't fix it

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes I do , but it's quite big , don't really wanna to post the whole thing here . I can do a screenshot of outcome and post it here if this helps

Comment: email sent . thank you so much in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking at this question, here is the working code:

```
def build_device_list(self):
    self.dev_store_len = len(self.device_list_store)
    for i, column_title in enumerate(["Device", "Model", "Serial Number","Size"]):
        self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, self.renderer, text=i)
        self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column)
        column.set_sort_column_id(i)
    self.renderer_status = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column_status = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Status",self.renderer_status, text=4, foreground=5)
    self.device_list_treeview.append_column(column_status)
    for x in range(0, self.dev_store_len):
        if self.device_list_store[x][4] == "READ-WRITE":
           self.device_list_store[x][5] = "Red"                
        else:
           self.device_list_store[x][5] = "Green" 
    self.scrollable_treelist = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.scrollable_treelist.set_vexpand(True)
    self.outter_box.pack_start(self.scrollable_treelist,False,True,0)
    self.scrollable_treelist.add(self.device_list_treeview)
```

Basically you need a hidden liststore column that holds string values with your color. Then the treeview column needs the foreground attribute set to that hidden column.